# #1062 - Duplicate entry '111' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a DB in through phpMyAdmin and I'm having trouble with this particular error repeating itself even though I cannot find where the duplicate entry is.

I changed some of the values of the PKs to see what would happen ie I changed 13 to 111, 12 to 112.  So even though I have changed the vlaue it's still seeing it as duplicate.

```
 SQL query:

--
-- Dumping data for table `gno_affiliates`
--
INSERT INTO  `gno_affiliates` (  `id` ,  `affiliate_name` ,  `affiliate_url` ) 
VALUES ( 111,  'Blackberry',  'http://www.blackberry.com' ) , ( 112,  'Android',      'http://www.android.com' ) , ( 12,  'I-Pod',  'http://www.I-Pod.com' ) , ( 14,  'Windows     Mobile',  'http://www.windowsmobile.com' ) , ( 15, 'Meego',  'http://www.meego.com' ) , (     16,  'Zombie Farm',  'http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/zombie-farm-2/id494655448?mt=8' ) ;


MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '111' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Here is the table code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gno_affiliates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `affiliate_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `affiliate_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the result of the query cowls suggested:
[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

As you can see there is only one entry for that id.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same.

Comment: The query clearly shows there is already an entry in the database with that ID. So this error `#1062 - Duplicate entry '111' for key 'PRIMARY' ` is completely expected. I am not sure what is meant by "as you can see there is only one entry for that id". The fact that the entry is rpesent will prevent you from inserting another entry with that ID

Answer (score 5):

There must already be an entry for that key in the table.

Run this query before running the insert to check:

```
SELECT * FROM gno_affiliates WHERE id = 111
```

It is possible to run this on the command line, however I reccommend downloading a SQL client as this will make your life easier going forward. I reccommend SQLYog:

http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list

Download the community edition (.exe) file.

Once downloaded, install the program and connect to your database using the connection details. Then you will have a query editor where you can execute this query.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question cowls, but where do I run this query?  I inserted it into the .sql file but that did nothing when importing it. I'm guessing in terminal somewhere? Also you can read the contents... there's no other 111 in that table!

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept the answer, else let us know the status